# Google CSE REST API : is v1 deprecated, is there a v2?

Tags: node.js, rest, api, google-custom-search

As many users of google CSE API, I received recently an email from "Google Custom Search" asking me "Please migrate to the Custom Search Element API 2.0". I checked [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element), but they only describe how to integrate a google search input in a website. I am currently using the REST endpoint of google cse from a Node.js program, so I cannot use this. [The documentation concerning the REST endpoint](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/using_rest) still references the V1, so I am a bit lost. I am wondering if this endpoint is also deprecated and will soon stop working, and if the v2 of the API is (or will be) available via a REST endpoint.

This subject has already been posted on [official Google forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/customsearch/OVm3d2SK2cY;context-place=forum/customsearch), it seems that many people worry about this, but for now there is no answer from google, so I'm trying this here !

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a satisfying answer, thanks to [Josh Sloat on the Google CSE forum](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/customsearch/OVm3d2SK2cY/J-impIzbDQAJ). Here is the answer he got from Google support : "Upon looking on a related issue and feedback from one of the Google Enterprise Search Support Team. If you are using JSON API to retrieve results and not using custom search element API 1.0/2.0 code snippets then you won't be impacted with the communication sent regarding the migration of custom search element API 1.0 to 2.0.".
So it appears that the REST API isn't affected by this update !

Answer (score 2):

Here to add that we had a tech support chat with Google today, and confirmed the same: JSON/REST v1 API is currently not going away. I'm glad to get clarity on this issue (for now...)